# Slow Performance on Power BI

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

I am pulling using a view on Power BI that consists of of 3 inner joins( 3 tables). This is the only approach I found to work for my case because Power BI does not allow multiple column indexing in relationships.

However even though I get the results I am looking for, the performance is extremely slow even on a single table in a page.

What is the best approach in terms of DAX or SQL to increase the efficiency.

SQL View Query

```
select  distinct   ClaimReceiptsInvoices.Amount, Paymentinfo.ClaimNumber,PaymentInfo.ReceiptInvoiceNumber,EFTConsolidationDetails.Payee,
EFTConsolidationDetails.Payeeid,EFTConsolidations.EFTNo,EFTConsolidations.EFTdate,Eftconsolidationdetails.Scheme,Eftconsolidationdetails.PaymentAmount,
EFTConsolidationDetails.WithheldAmount 

from Paymentinfo inner join eftconsolidationdetails 
on Paymentinfo.ClaimNumber = eftconsolidationdetails.claim and Paymentinfo.ReceiptInvoiceNumber = EFTConsolidationDetails.InvoiceNumber inner join EFTConsolidations 
on EFTConsolidationDetails.EFTNo = EFTConsolidations.EFTNo and EFTConsolidationDetails.PayeeID = EFTConsolidations.PayeeID inner join ClaimReceiptsInvoices
on ClaimReceiptsInvoices.Claim = PaymentInfo.ClaimNumber and ClaimReceiptsInvoices.InvoiceNumber=PaymentInfo.ReceiptInvoiceNumber
```

I am in need of the field "PaymentAmount"

Comment: Could you [share](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) the exection plan? and if possible the query

Comment: "Power BI does not allow multiple column indexing in relationships" it doesn't?

Comment: Are you using Import mode or Direct Query mode? Basically the performance will depend up the mode that you use in your power bi.

Comment: @balaji I am using Direct Query

Comment: Why `distinct`?

Comment: Please try using Import mode, This mode performs extremely fast performance.

Comment: @Arvo I need to avoid duplicates.

Comment: be sure to have updated statistics on the tables https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/update-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @balaji The import mode works quite significantly faster. Thanks for that

Comment: You are welcome, Import mode is always preferable as you will be able to best utilize the capabilities of power bi.